# Distributed model calculation

Tags: r

I'm having an issue with the following code. I'm trying to calculate n models (in this case - 10000 models) with one variable. I'm trying to speed up the code using multithreading. I have few questions regarding the code:

1. I can see that parLapply function doesn't return any results - what is the issue there?
2. I tried to meassure the execution of that code and it seems that usage of more clusters / threads slows down the process. Why is that happening?
3. Is the applied method correct way of speeding up the code?

```
library(parallel)
library(foreach) 
library(doSNOW)
library(doParallel)
library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)

col_names <- c("Y",paste("x",1:10000,sep=""))
X_names <- paste("x",1:10000,sep="")
matrix <- matrix(0,1000,10001)
colnames(matrix) <- col_names
set.seed = 555
matrix[,"Y"] <- sample(1:100,1000,replace=TRUE)
for (i in X_names){
  matrix[,i] <- matrix[,"Y"]+rnorm(1000,0,1)
}

data_gen = as.data.frame(matrix)


ModelParallel <- function(data, y_name, x_name, noclusters, method) {

  results <- list()
  build_model <- function(formula) {
    model <- lm(formula, data = data_gen)
    result <- summary(model)$coefficients[, 1]
    names_of_variables <- names(result)
    result_list <- list(Names = names_of_variables, Coef = result)
    return(result_list)
  }
  
  if (method == "parLapply") {
    cl <- makeCluster(noclusters)
    clusterExport(cl, "data_gen")
    
    results <- parLapply(cl, x_name, function(model) {
      formula <- as.formula(paste(y_name, "~", paste(model, collapse = "+")))
      estimation <- build_model(formula)
      return(estimation)
    })
    
    stopCluster(cl)
  }
  
  else if (method == "for") {
    split_models <- split(x_name, 1:noclusters)
    cl <- makeCluster(noclusters)
    clusterExport(cl, "data_gen")
    
    results <- parLapply(cl, split_models, function(split) {
      split_results <- list()
      for (i in 1:length(split)) {
        model <- split[[i]]
        formula <- as.formula(paste(y_name, "~", paste(model, collapse = "+")))
        estimation <- build_model(formula)
        split_results[[i]] <- estimation
      }
      return(split_results)
    })
    
    stopCluster(cl)

    results <- do.call(c, results)
    
    return(results)
  }
}


list_of_models <- paste0("x", 1:10000)

noclusters <- 2
results1 <- ModelParallel(data_gen, "Y", list_of_models, noclusters, method = "parLapply")

noclusters <- 10
results2 <- ModelParallel(data_gen, "Y", list_of_models, noclusters, method = "parLapply")


noclusters <- 2
results1 <- ModelParallel(data_gen, "Y", list_of_models, noclusters, method = "for")

noclusters <- 10
results2 <- ModelParallel(data_gen, "Y", list_of_models, noclusters, method = "for")
```